# How to exclude an aar from building my project?

Tags: android, maven, android-studio

I have a project, it depends on some `aar`s. The `aar`s are all compiled from maven.
For example, the ***build.gradle*** contains lines like this:

```
compile 'com.aa.a'  
compile 'com.aa.b'  
compile 'com.aa.c'
```

If `com.aa.a` contains `com.aa.c` of version ***1.0***, `com.aa.c` is of version ***1.1-SNAPSHOT***, but I don't know which one `aar` imports the `com.aa.c` of version 1.0.
The `com.aa.c` of version ***1.0*** has different ARTIFACT_ID with `com.aa.c` of version ***1.1-SNAPSHOT***.
The problem is how I can exclude the `com.aa.c` of version ***1.0*** in ***build.gradle*** or some other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by adding this into the ***build.gradle*** file.

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'your-group_id', module: 'your-artifact_id'
}
```

Reference [gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html).